# Getting dynamic width of div after rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, flexbox, use-ref

I want to get the width of a dynamic div after it's painted, but I can't tell how.
This is what I am doing :

```js
const ref=useRef();
useEffect(()=>{
console.log('REF',ref.current.offSetWidth)
},[])



return (
<div ref={ref}>


</div>
```

I tried window.resize eventListener, but it only gets triggered if the screen dimensions changed. My question is there anyway to get the width of a div after it renders on the screen ? I'm not setting the width beforehand, it's just taking 100% of parent element inside a flex box

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver), a simple implementation with React could be something like this:

```
import {useRef, useEffect} from 'react'

export default function App() {
  const divRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    new ResizeObserver(() => {
      console.log('Width: ', divRef.current.clientWidth)
    }).observe(divRef.current)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div ref={divRef}>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working I think. Here is a short Typescript implementation to show my point:

```js
...

const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();
    return (
        <div ref={ref as MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>}>
            <button onClick={() => console.log('REF', ref?.current?.clientWidth)}>TEST</button>
        </div>
    );

...
```

Console result on button click before resizing:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Console result on button click after resizing:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I guess the reason you never see the changes is that you have a use effect here that only runs once. Also note that changes in the ref object will not automatically trigger a re-render.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCmz4.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWpVM.png